# Convert numpy.ndarray to lowercase

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am new to `numpy`, I am trying to convert and `numpy.ndarray` elements to lowercase. I have an array(after printing) as follows:

```
[247.5 247.5 247.5 247.5 247.5 247.5 247.5 247.5 49.5 247.5 247.5 495
 3019.5 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 'Total Bill' nan 247.5 247.5 247.5 742.5 742.5 nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan]
```

It's an database series actually which I have converted into `np.array`.

`array.shape` is `(39,)` wants to convert lowercase so that output will be

```
[247.5 247.5 247.5 247.5 247.5 247.5 247.5 247.5 49.5 247.5 247.5 495
 3019.5 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 'total bill' nan 247.5 247.5 247.5 742.5 742.5 nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan]
```

Comment: Is this a string dtype array, or object dtype?  If object, why is it an array instead of a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
a = np.array([x.lower() if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in arr])
```

Comment: Will `a` be still an `np.array`?

Comment: Hmmm, I think not. Corrected.

Comment: Is there no direct method as without converting it into array?

Comment: It's giving error as `Wrong number of items passed 39, placement implies 1`